# Python Data Scraping with Beautiful Soup - geting Data from within a href

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I'm pretty new to Python and getting to know Beautiful Soup.
So I have this problem: I need to get data from an event company, specifically contact data. They have this main tables with all participant names and their location. But to get the contact data (phone, email) you need to press on each of the company name from the table and it opens the new window with all the additional information. I'm looking for a way to get that info from a href and combine it with the data in a main table.

So I can get the table and all the href:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen


test_url = "https://standconstruction.messe-duesseldorf.de/vis/v1/en/hallindex/1.09?oid=2656&lang=2"
test_data = urlopen(test_url)
test_html = test_data.read()
test_data.close()

page_soup = soup(test_html, "html.parser")

test_table = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "exh-table-col"})
print(test_table)
```

As a result I get all the table and have this kind of info (example of one row), including Name, Adress and href:

```
<a class="flush" href="/vis/v1/en/exhibitors/aluminium2020.2661781?oid=2656&amp;lang=2">
<h2 class="exh-table-item__name" itemprop="name">Aerospace Engineering Equipment (Suzhou) Co LTD</h2>
</a>

</div>, <div class="exh-table-col exh-table-col--address">
<span class=""><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>  <span class="link-fix--text">Hall 9 / G57</span></span>
```

That's where my problem starts, I have no Idea how to get the additional data from the href and combine it with the main data.

I would be very thankful for any possible solutions or at least a tip, where can I find one.

Updating the question:
I needed a Table which contains the information of the following columns:
1.Name; 2.Hall; 3.PDF; 4.Phone; 5.Email.

If you collect the Data by hand - to get the Phone and Email you need to click the appropriate link for it to show. 
I wanted to know if there was a way to export the Phone and Email from those Link and add them to the first 3 columns using Python.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "how to get the additional data from the href and combine it with the main data". Please edit your question with examples of your desired output.

Comment: @JackFleeting below is his goal

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Thx! That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JackFleeting thx for the tip. I updated the question. I hope it would be clearer now in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep

params = {
    "oid": "2656",
    "lang": "2"
}


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url, params=params)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        target = soup.select("div.exh-table-item")

        names = [name.h2.text for name in target]
        hall = [hall.span.text.strip() for hall in target]
        pdf = [pdf.select_one("a.color--darkest")['href'] for pdf in target]
        links = [f"{url[:46]}{link.a['href']}" for link in target]

        phones = []
        emails = []

        for num, link in enumerate(links):
            print(f"Extracting {num +1} of {len(links)}")

            r = req.get(link)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            goal = soup.select_one("div[class^=push--bottom]")

            try:
                phone = goal.select_one("span[itemprop=telephone]").text
            except:
                phone = "N/A"

            try:
                email = goal.select_one("a[itemprop=email]").text
            except:
                email = "N/A"

            emails.append(email)
            phones.append(phone)
            sleep(1)

        df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(names, hall, pdf, phones, emails)), columns=[
                          "Name", "Hall", "PDF", "Phone", "Email"])
        print(df)
        df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)


main("https://standconstruction.messe-duesseldorf.de/vis/v1/en/hallindex/1.09")
```

Output: [View Online](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/63085ab25da550cb4ff4ea4cd86270db/data.csv)

[image]

Comment: just one question for my understanding, this parameters, how do you select the right numbers? 
params = {
    "oid": "2656",
    "lang": "2"
}

Comment: @Se_D it's the params which you used within the original link!

Comment: True... completely overlooked it. Thank you!